# Understanding API and how to send proper CURL request

Tags: php, api, curl

I am trying to figure out how to use Pin Payments API, function get charge.

https://pin.net.au/docs/api/charges#get-charge

As you can see they provide an example of the request using CURL

```
curl https://test-api.pin.net.au/1/charges/ch_bZ3RhJnIUZ8HhfvH8CCvfA -u your-secret-api-key:
```

I am just not sure how do I convert that to PHP, how do I pass my API key and how to pass charge ID so that the URL understood by the server.

Please help me comple the code below:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://test-api.pin.net.au/1/charges/ch_bZ3RhJnIUZ8HhfvH8CCvfA',

));
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Look up the `u` command line parameter: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

   It represents the username and the password being used for the request.
2. Look up [curl_setopt()](http://php.net/curl_setopt). `CURLOPT_USERPWD` is the option for setting these credentials:

   ```
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'apikey:');

   // or

   curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
     CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
     CURLOPT_URL            => 'https://test-api.pin.net.au/1/charges/ch_bZ3RhJnIUZ8HhfvH8CCvfA',
     CURLOPT_USERPWD        => 'apikey:'
   ));
   ```

Please pay attention to the trailing colon! It separates the username from the password, which is empty in this case.